# How to create xml file from a string in android

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to get an XML file from a String in android, the code is constantly giving me an exception. Below is my Code

```
public void createXML (String xmlString)
    {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();  

        DocumentBuilder builder;  
        try  
        {  
            builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();  

            // Use String reader  
            Document document = builder.parse( new InputSource( new StringReader( xmlString ) ) );  

            TransformerFactory tranFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();  
            Transformer aTransformer = tranFactory.newTransformer();  
            Source src = new DOMSource( document );  
            String path = "ScriptEmails/"+ "my"+".xml";
            String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+File.separator+"Screenwriter"+File.separator+path;

            Result dest = new StreamResult( new File( filepath ) );  
            aTransformer.transform( src, dest );  
        } catch (Exception e)  
        {  
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
            e.toString();

        }  
    }
```

I get exception on this line `Document document = builder.parse( new InputSource( new StringReader( xmlString ) ) );`

My `xmlString` contain the following value

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<FinalDraft DocumentType="Script" Template="No" Version="1">

<Paragraph Type =Scene Heading>
<Text>
HELLO
</Text>
</Paragraph>
<Paragraph Type =Action>
<Text>
HELLO

This is my first scene

</Text>
</Paragraph>
<Paragraph Type =Character>
<Text>
HELLO

This is my first scene

HASS
</Text>
</Paragraph>
<Paragraph Type =Dialogue>
<Text>
HELLO

This is my first scene

HASS
Cheetay kesa hay Kia scene 
</Text>
</Paragraph>
<Paragraph Type =Dialogue>
<Text>
HELLO

This is my first scene

HASS
Cheetay kesa hay Kia scene 
chal rha hay ajkel

</Text>
</Paragraph>
<Paragraph Type =Character>
<Text>
HELLO

This is my first scene

HASS
Cheetay kesa hay Kia scene 
chal rha hay ajkel

AHNE
</Text>
</Paragraph>
<Paragraph Type =Dialogue>
<Text>
HELLO

This is my first scene

HASS
Cheetay kesa hay Kia scene 
chal rha hay ajkel

AHNE
Kuch nhe boy scene is really 
</Text>
</Paragraph>
<Paragraph Type =Dialogue>
<Text>
HELLO

This is my first scene

HASS
Cheetay kesa hay Kia scene 
chal rha hay ajkel

AHNE
Kuch nhe boy scene is really 
baf actually things have gotten 
</Text>
</Paragraph>
<Paragraph Type =Dialogue>
<Text>
HELLO

This is my first scene

HASS
Cheetay kesa hay Kia scene 
chal rha hay ajkel

AHNE
Kuch nhe boy scene is really 
baf actually things have gotten 
worse

</Text>
</Paragraph>
</FinalDraft>
```

Let me know if something is wrong with my code or with my xmlString.

Here is the LogCat

```
12-06 12:06:56.983: W/System.err(28508): org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: attr value delimiter missing! (position:START_TAG <Paragraph Type='Script'>@4:18 in java.io.StringReader@4239c190) 
12-06 12:06:56.983: W/System.err(28508):    at org.apache.harmony.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:146)
12-06 12:06:56.983: W/System.err(28508):    at com.example.screenwritter.Dropboxupload.createXML(Dropboxupload.java:356)
12-06 12:06:56.983: W/System.err(28508):    at com.example.screenwritter.Dropboxupload$4.onClick(Dropboxupload.java:339)
12-06 12:06:56.983: W/System.err(28508):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3574)
12-06 12:06:56.983: W/System.err(28508):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14293)
12-06 12:06:56.983: W/System.err(28508):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
12-06 12:06:56.983: W/System.err(28508):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-06 12:06:56.983: W/System.err(28508):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-06 12:06:56.983: W/System.err(28508):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4448)
12-06 12:06:56.983: W/System.err(28508):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-06 12:06:56.983: W/System.err(28508):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-06 12:06:56.983: W/System.err(28508):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
12-06 12:06:56.993: W/System.err(28508):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
12-06 12:06:56.993: W/System.err(28508):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Actually i want to read and ride an .FDX ( Final Draft ) file. which is actually in XML format

Comment: no error log as it goes into the Exception block and nothing happens then, even not in the logcat

Comment: can anybody post a right string format, that i can check with, weather there is a problem with the code or string

Comment: Print the stack trace with `e.printstacktrace()` and post the Exception details.

Comment: e.printStackTrace() instead of e.toString()

Comment: I would start with an empty document and add the nodes gradually.

Comment: Log added, please check

Comment: The problem is with the String, i have figured it out. Thank you so much @18446744073709551615

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like This

Put your Xml file in asset Folder:

```
String xml;
 Document doc;
 try{
 xml=getXML(getAssets().open("yourxmlfilename.xml"));
 }catch(Exception e){
     Log.d("Error",e.toString());
  }
 doc = XMLfromString(xml);
```

where getXML and XMLfromString method are as shown below

```
//getXML   method
 public static String getXML(InputStream is)throws IOException {

    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
    ByteArrayOutputStream buf = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int result = bis.read();
    while(result != -1) {
      byte b = (byte)result;
      buf.write(b);
      result = bis.read();
    }        
    return buf.toString();
}


   //XMLfromString   method
  public final static Document XMLfromString(String xml){
     Document doc = null;

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            try {

          DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

          InputSource is = new InputSource();
              is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
              doc = db.parse(is); 

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
          System.out.println("XML parse error: " + e.getMessage());
          return null;
        } catch (SAXException e) {
          System.out.println("Wrong XML file structure: " + e.getMessage());
                return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
          System.out.println("I/O exeption: " + e.getMessage());
          return null;
        }

            return doc;

  }
```

Comment: I want to create an xml file first of all, i actually have a string saved in DB and i want to convert it into xml. so should i just place an empty xml into the assets folder

Answer (score 0):

Get the String for DB, and then save it to file with ***.xml** extension. you job is done.

```
public void createXML (String xmlString)
{
    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/folder_name");    
    myDir.mkdirs();

    String filename = "fileName"+".xml";
    File file = new File (myDir, filename);
    FileOutputStream outputStream;

        try {
          outputStream = openFileOutput(file, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
          outputStream.write(xmlString.getBytes());// for encodeing type use 'xmlString.getBytes("UTF-8")'
          outputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Add READ-WRITE permission on the Manifest-

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

For added security perspective you can check [is External Storage Writable](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html#WriteExternalStorage).